# How do I get a traditional visual studio solution out of old SourceSafe nonsense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have to figure out what needs to be done to make a very old/shelved/unfinished C# asp.net code base into a working application if it's even possible.

I was pointed to the source where there's just a few things in the root, the important one seems to be this data folder.

It contains a whole bunch of folders mostly titled a, b, c, etc. And those contain files called something like baaaaaa or baaaaaaa.b. I can open some of these up in notepad and see plane old C# source code but it's basically meaningless in this organization.

I've never used SourceSafe, but from googling I guess this is how SourceSafe stored files and their changes or something?

If I have what I've described but no traditional solutions or source is it possible to get the original organized solution with properly name classes and such? Can I even use this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a SourceSafe library.  You need to:

1. Get VSS (Visual Source Safe, v6.0d is still available) on your client.
2. Point it to that root directory as a VSS library.

Then you should see the projects tree and be able to extract everything.

Comment: Thank you, just gotta get it all setup to verify.